# how to Add nested object models to the list?

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have some object models like this :

```
             var x= new XModel()
              {
                end_date = "2017-12-15",
                page = 1,
                start_date = "2014-12-01",
                group_by = new List<string> { "numbers" },
                filter = new Filter() { numbers= new List<int> {1620} ,names= null, deleted= null, added = null }
            };
```

or this one :

```
  var y= new YModel
        {

            Title = "test title",     
            GenderType = Gender.Men,
            Oss = "ALL",
            Devices = new List<string> { "11", "12" },
            Categories = new List<string> { "11", "12" },
         }
```

i want to add these models to the list, the problem is , i tried to wrote a generic method to add all object models like above to the list.
My current method is :

```
    internal static List<UrlParameter> GetParams<TModel>(this TModel entity)
    {
        var parameters = new List<UrlParameter>();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propVal = propertyInfo.GetValue(entity, null);

            if (propVal == null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new UrlParameter(propertyInfo.Name, ""));
                continue;
            }

            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            {
                if (propVal.GetType().IsPrimitiveType())
                {
                    parameters.Add(new UrlParameter(propertyInfo.Name, propVal));
                }
                else
                {
                    var arr = propVal as IEnumerable;
                    if (arr.HasArrayContainPrimitiveType())
                        parameters.Add(new UrlParameter(propertyInfo.Name, $"[{ToJsonArray(arr)}]"));
                    else
                        parameters.AddRange(from object obj in arr
                                            select GetParams(obj)
                            into subparams
                                            select new UrlParameter(propertyInfo.Name, subparams));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (propVal.GetType().IsPrimitiveType())
                    parameters.Add(new UrlParameter(propertyInfo.Name, propVal));
                else
                {
                    var subparams = GetParams(propVal);
                    parameters.Add(new UrlParameter(propertyInfo.Name, subparams));
                }
            }
        }

        return parameters;
    }
```

it works fine for most of my models, but the `x` where contains `filter` makes me a problem, the `numbers` value saved like this `filter=numbers%3d%255b1620%255d%2c%2c%2c%2c%2c%2c%2c` , and the rest of the fields disappeare.
i want to add `numbers, names, deleted and added` as key, value parameter nested in filter, can you please help me to fixed this?

Comment: How is your filter code ?

Comment: my filter code is :
        public class Filter
    {
        public IEnumerable<int> numbers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> names { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> deleted{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> added{ get; set; }

Comment: You have to use List<int> istead of Ienumerable, ienumerable is not cannot be serialized

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, I've changed all IEnumerables to List, as you told, but the result is as same as before.

Comment: I tried to see if I could debug your program, and I faced some issues. First of all which kind of project is it (WPF, MVC, WEB or CONSOLE) ? And what is UrlParameter ? is it a class you have created or is it from a .DLL ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, I'm using is Asp.Net Web Application.
UrlParameter is a key, value class like a Dictionary.

Comment: Is it communicating with a WCF ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101755/discussion-between-nawed-nabi-zada-and-mina).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `MultipartFormDataContent` class.

it converts all the nested model as they are.